# Regex camelcase in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use regex to convert a string like this "North Korea"
to a string like "northKorea" - does someone know how I might accomplish this in c# ?

Cheers

Comment: why regex? why not replace all spaces for empty strings and lowercase the first character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just split it and put it back together:

```
string[] split = ("North Korea").Split(' ');

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < split.Count(); i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
        sb.Append(split[i].ToLower());
    else
        sb.Append(split[i]);
}
```

Edit: Switched to a StringBuilder instead, like Bazzz suggested.

Comment: +1 I like the approach, but string concats are not such a good idea for performance and memory management. Perhaps you should add the same example with a StringBuilder.

Comment: I agree with @Bazzz every time Split/Concat is used a unicorn dies.

Answer (score 7):

if you know all your input strings are in title case (like "North Korea") you can simply do:

```
string input = "North Korea"; 
input = input.Replace(" ",""); //remove spaces
string output = char.ToLower(input[0]) + 
              input.Substring(1); //make first char lowercase
                                  // output = "northKorea"
```

if some of your input is not in title case you can use TextInfo.ToTitleCase

```
string input = "NoRtH kORea"; 
input = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(input);
input = input.Replace(" ",""); //remove spaces
string output = char.ToLower(input[0]) + 
          input.Substring(1); //make first char lowercase
                              // output = "northKorea"
```

Answer (score 4):

Forget regex.
All you need is a camelCase conversion algorithm:

See here:
http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/096fea45-b426-40fd-8beb-dec49d8a8662.aspx

Use this one:

```
string camelCase = ConvertCaseString(a, Case.CamelCase);
```

Copy-pasted in case it goes offline:

```
void Main() {
    string a = "background color-red.brown";
    string camelCase = ConvertCaseString(a, Case.CamelCase);
    string pascalCase = ConvertCaseString(a, Case.PascalCase);
}

/// <summary>
/// Converts the phrase to specified convention.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="phrase"></param>
/// <param name="cases">The cases.</param>
/// <returns>string</returns>
static string ConvertCaseString(string phrase, Case cases)
{
    string[] splittedPhrase = phrase.Split(' ', '-', '.');
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (cases == Case.CamelCase)
    {
        sb.Append(splittedPhrase[0].ToLower());
        splittedPhrase[0] = string.Empty;
    }
    else if (cases == Case.PascalCase)
        sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (String s in splittedPhrase)
    {
        char[] splittedPhraseChars = s.ToCharArray();
        if (splittedPhraseChars.Length > 0)
        {
            splittedPhraseChars[0] = ((new String(splittedPhraseChars[0], 1)).ToUpper().ToCharArray())[0];
        }
        sb.Append(new String(splittedPhraseChars));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

enum Case
{
    PascalCase,
    CamelCase
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice approach, but it does feel a little like shooting a mosquito with a cannon. It's still good and relevant info, though, even if only to let the OP rethink his/her Regex ideas. :)

Answer (score 2):

This builds on Paolo Falabella's answer as a String extension and handles a few boundary cases such as empty string. Since there is some confusion between CamelCase and camelCase, I called it LowerCamelCase as described on Wikipedia. I resisted the temptation to go with nerdCaps.

```
internal static string ToLowerCamelCase( this string input )
{
    string output = "";            
    if( String.IsNullOrEmpty( input ) == false  )
    {
        output = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase( input ); //in case not Title Case
        output = output.Replace( " ", "" ); //remove any white spaces between words
        if( String.IsNullOrEmpty( output ) == false )  //handles the case where input is "  "
        {
            output = char.ToLower( output[0] ) + output.Substring( 1 ); //lowercase first (even if 1 character string)
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Use:

```
string test = "Foo Bar";
test = test.ToLowerCamelCase();
... //test is now "fooBar"
```

**Update:**
toong raised a good point in the comments - this will not work for graphemes. See the link provided by  toong. There are also examples of iterating graphemes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15111719/746754) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2056882/746754) if you want to tweak the above code for graphemes.

Comment: I like your approach. One very minor issue (which is in all answers here I guess): output[0] might fail if the first letter is composed of combining characters ("a\u0304\u0308" = "ā̈") or surrogate pairs ("\uD950\uDF21" = "��") ? You might want to use StringInfo.GetNextTextElement - see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0hcb622.aspx

Comment: @toong - that is a good point. I have updated to reference your comment and added some links.

Answer (score 1):

`String::Split` definitely is one of my pet peeves. Also, none of the other answers deal with:

- Cultures
- All forms of word seperators
- Numbers
- What happens when it starts with word seperators

I tried to get it as close as possible to what you would find in base class library code:

```
static string ToCamelCaseInvariant(string value) { return ToCamelCase(value, true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
static string ToCamelCaseInvariant(string value, bool changeWordCaps) { return ToCamelCase(value, changeWordCaps, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }

static string ToCamelCase(string value) { return ToCamelCase(value, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); }
static string ToCamelCase(string value, bool changeWordCaps) { return ToCamelCase(value, changeWordCaps, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); }

/// <summary>
/// Converts the given string value into camelCase.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The value.</param>
/// <param name="changeWordCaps">If set to <c>true</c> letters in a word (apart from the first) will be lowercased.</param>
/// <param name="culture">The culture to use to change the case of the characters.</param>
/// <returns>
/// The camel case value.
/// </returns>
static string ToCamelCase(string value, bool changeWordCaps, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (culture == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("culture");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return value;

    var result = new StringBuilder(value.Length);
    var lastWasBreak = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = value[i];
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || char.IsPunctuation(c) || char.IsSeparator(c))
        {
            lastWasBreak = true;
        }
        else if (char.IsNumber(c))
        {
            result.Append(c);
            lastWasBreak = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (result.Length == 0)
            {
                result.Append(char.ToLower(c, culture));
            }
            else if (lastWasBreak)
            {
                result.Append(char.ToUpper(c, culture));
            }
            else if (changeWordCaps)
            {
                result.Append(char.ToLower(c, culture));
            }
            else
            {
                result.Append(c);
            }

            lastWasBreak = false;
        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}

// Tests
'  This is a test. 12345hello world' = 'thisIsATest12345HelloWorld'
'--north korea' = 'northKorea'
'!nOrTH koreA' = 'northKorea'
'System.Console.' = 'systemConsole'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var input = "Hi my name is Rony";
var subStrs = input.ToLower().Split(' ');
var output = "";

foreach(var s in subStrs)
{
   if(s!=subStrs[0])
      output += s.First().ToString().ToUpper() + String.Join("", s.Skip(1));
   else
      output += s;
}
```

should get "`hiMyNameIsRony`" as the output

Answer (score 0):

```
    string toCamelCase(string s)
    {
        if (s.Length < 2) return s.ToLower();
        return Char.ToLowerInvariant(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
    }
```

similar to Paolo Falabella's code but survives empty strings and 1 char strings.