# String EndsWith(alphabet); C#

Tags: .net, regex, c#-4.0

I Have a string 
string name="ajsbbc<<(either hold an alphabet or some symbol at the end )
Now i want a condition that identify a string contain [a-zA-Z] at the end(true/false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function in the Char class that does this already.

```
    string name = "ajsbbc";

    if (Char.IsLetter(name[name.Length - 1]))
        Console.WriteLine("True");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("False");
```

Comment: This matches more than A-Za-z this will write true for Café `"Caf\u00e9" // U+00E9 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE` but then again will write false for when a grapheme is used in Café `"Cafe\u0301" // U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056866/enumerating-a-string-by-grapheme-instead-of-character for a solution that can deal with a grapheme

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Regex solution:

```
Regex.IsMatch(name, "[a-zA-Z]$");
```

Comment: But how this ragex will able to check last char only

Comment: $ marks the end of the string so if there exists a match for `[a-zA-Z]` then the string being tested must end with a character in the set of `[a-zA-Z]`.

Answer (score 1):

store last char of your string at temp string and then check your temp string with regular exp 
`Regex lettersOnly = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]$");`
where

- ^ means "begin matching at start of string"
- [a-zA-Z] means "match lower case and upper case letters a-z"
- $ means "only match if cursor is at end of string"
  tri it (i am not sure if it work)

Comment: Remove the ^ and there's no need to pre-parse the string to get just the last char.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function and send your string as parameter to this

```
    private bool IsAlphabet(string input)
    {
        bool alphabet = false;

        char ch = input[input.Length - 1];

        if ((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))
            alphabet = true;

        return alphabet;
    }
```

Comment: Ajit will you please explain me the condition you mentioned above , just for my sake and not to test your knowlwdge(i mean is it possible to apply aloop in if condition over alphabets)

Comment: Some suggestion. You need to check whether the string is null or empty. Also you just say return ((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')); and avoid the local bool variable. you can also make this an extension method.